# InkWell effect starts delayed if using onDoubleTap; want to trigger that as soon as the widget gets touched

Tags: flutter, gesture-recognition

If you are using `onTap` & `onDoubleTap` side by side with an `InkWell`, then a single tap gets delayed (300ms). I know the time is needed for the recognition of a double tap but also the effect is delayed, and that's a bad user interaction feeling.

**What I've tried:**
I found out, that the `InkWell` effect is startet as soon as any tap event callback gets called. If I use `onTap` alone, the callback and the effect is started instantly on the first touch; if I use `onTap` and `onDoubleTap`, the effect gets delayed.

I also tried using `onTapDown`, but this also gets delayed (possilbe Bug?)

```dart
child: InkWell(
  onTap: () { print("Tap"); },                // gets delayed 300ms
  onDoubleTap: () { print("Double Tap"); }, 
  onTapDown: (x) { print("Tap Down"); }       // gets delayed 300ms
}
```

**So my question:**
Is it anyway possible to change the InkWell (GestureDetector) to start the effect instantly. I think the solution could be, to change the onTapDown behavior; this should be called immediately if the user touches the widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've now found a simple **solution**. I am only using the `onTap` function of the `InkWell` and have written the `onDoubleTap` algorithm my self. So the splash effect runs immediately because the original `onDoubleTap` isn't used. The tap function itself gets delayed (as it also would have been by using the original `onDoubleTap` function).

**Pup.dev package**
I've written a pub.dev package called `InkWellSplash`. Additional to the splash feature, you can now adjust the maximal time between two taps to recognize a double tap.

I'm pretty sure this package comes in handy and is useful for several developer

**Links**

[Pub.dev - InklWellSplash](https://pub.dev/packages/inkwell_splash)

[GitHub - InkWellSplash](https://github.com/ManuelRohrauer/inkwell_splash)

[Interactive Example](https://dartpad.dev/embed-flutter.html?gh_owner=ManuelRohrauer&gh_repo=inkwell_splash&gh_path=dartpad_example&run=true)

Comment: I am having the same problem and even 300 milliseconds is too long when comparing it to native touch effect on my phone.
A specially when the onTap callback is called way before these 300 milliseconds, so if you quickly tap and navigate to some other page, you wont even have a chance to see the ripple.
Is there a way to make it even faster?

Comment: To clarify what exactly do you want to make faster: The ripple effect, or the call of the onTap function? the ripple effect start immetiately after click, so there is no delay. The callback for the onTap function, starts after the time which you can set via the property `doubleTapTime: Duration(milliseconds: 300)`

Comment: I am talking about the ripple. 
I want the ripple to appear immediately when I put my finger on the screen, right now i need to hold it about 300 milliseconds to see it and if i do it rapidly enough I don't see the ripple at all. When you say 'after the click' it wont be seen when you tap rapidly. 
This is how it behaves in native apps, at least on Android.

Comment: Did you test the Interactive Example? For the original InkWell it's right, the ripple will delay 300ms. But that's the reason i wrote the InkWellSplash. Here the ripple appears immediately after you put your finger down.

Comment: Ohh, sorry, I was focused on the discussion and  didn't noticed that..
I will give it a try in did!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declared locally within the widget
final ValueNotifier<int> pressCount = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
final ValueNotifier<Timer> _timer =
      ValueNotifier<Timer>(Timer(Duration.zero, () {}));
       ...
InkWell{
       ...
   onTapDown: (tapDownDetails) {
        pressCount.value++;
        if (pressCount.value >= 2) {
             //Do Something
             pressCount.value = 0;
        } else {
             _timer.value = Timer(
             const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
             () {
                 pressCount.value = 0;
                });
        }
   },
        ...
}
```

Not sure why, but now when I use onLongPress and onDoubleTap there is a weird result.(I am getting a ink effect where it slowly covers my whole widget) So this is what i use for a quick homemade remedy to replace onDoubleTap().

This solution is using Provider package, because I didnt want to use StatefulWidgets. If you are using a statefulwidget. you can just create without ValueNotifier, because StatelessWidget require variables to be final(immutable), but i require immutable variables, so i wrapped it in value notifier.