# onDoubleTap makes onTap very slow

Tags: flutter

When onDoubleTap is used, it will be very slow when you single tap.

Is this normal?

Comment: Did you  test in a real device?

Comment: Yes, but the device target is desktop not mobile phone.

Comment: I test in my computer. Not problem for me, But GestureDetector better work. So use GestureDetector instead of Inkwell.

Comment: If onDoubleTap is enabled, my single tap will be delayed, not only inkwell, but also gesturedector, datacell, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a reference through this link hope this will work for you [StackOverflowOnTapIssue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61236928/inkwell-effect-starts-delayed-if-using-ondoubletap-want-to-trigger-that-as-soon)

Comment: not only InkWell, but in dataCell also.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this happens so Flutter can distinguish weather a single tap or double tap event fired.
The way I fixed this in my project was by detecting double tap inside the onTap event using `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch`

For example:

```
     onTapDown: (_) {
        int currMills = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        if ((currMills - lastClickmilliseconds) < 500) {
          onDoubleTap();
        } else {
          lastClickmilliseconds = currMills;
          onSingleTap();
        }
      },
```

make sure you initialize lastClickmilliseconds outside the build function:

```
int lastClickmilliseconds = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```